# Codename One - Change the background color of the Toolbar

Tags: codenameone

I want to change the background color of the `Toolbar` but for whatever reason it ignores the background I set
[image]

It should be totally white but it's just a tiny bit more blue than it should be. How would I use the right color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the color to be used and not an image you need to set the background type to NONE and set the color. You also need to override the Border entry and select `Empty` as the border type.

Comment: I've tried that but it becomes black it seems, did I do something wrong?

[https://i.imgur.com/6THg8jh.png](https://i.imgur.com/6THg8jh.png)

Comment: What did you define in the color section?

Comment: I played with the colors a bit more and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone trying to do this with only java and CSS, this worked for me:

```
    form.getToolbar().setUIID(UIID);
    form.getToolbar().getUnselectedStyle().setBorder(Border.createEmpty(),true);
    form.getToolbar().getUnselectedStyle().setBgTransparency(255);
```

then change the color with "background-color: your-color" under that ID in the CSS file.